# can't find httpclient and gps library for basic4android

Tags: android, gps, basic4android

I'm new to basic4android for develop Android applications.

I need gps / httpclient library for testing a sample.

Or could you give me another solution for writing a gps and web service call application in basic4android?

thank you

Comment: can't complete this tutorial : http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/6592-gps-tutorial.html

Comment: What problem do you have? Any error? Which version of B4A are you using 1.6 or 1.7?

Comment: hi , i using 1.7 version and i need to give location of gps

Comment: i need location data ( latitude , longitude )

Comment: If you think your question has been answered, please make it as ready.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to add the GPS library to your project. After that is really easy:

First, you have to declare a GPS objet:

```
Sub Process_Globals
    Dim GPS1 As GPS
End Sub
```

After that, you have to initialice the object:

```
Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean)
    If FirstTime Then
        GPS1.Initialize("GPS")
    End If
End Sub
```

Then you have to use, the GPS event that is called when location has changed:

```
Sub GPS_LocationChanged (Location1 As Location)
    Dim Lat, Long as string
    Lat = Location1.ConvertToMinutes(Location1.Latitude)
    Lon = Location1.ConvertToMinutes(Location1.Longitude)
End Sub
```

Now you'll have to stablish connection with send service, and send data.

Comment: i don't have GPS Library and can't download it , if you have it thank , can you email to me ? sabetsoft@gmail.com

Comment: In order to download additional libraries, It's needed to be a licensed user, have you bought the program?

Comment: No, there is no way without GPS library. What libraries do you have?

Comment: i solve my problem with library , i will use GPS in Service please help.

Comment: how to make service for start at boot and access GPS location change ?